# Can changing database owner affect permissions or role memberships?

Tags: sql-server

A couple years ago we ran into a situation where we were changing the database owner from a DBA's login to sa, and immediately thereafter we received a complaint that the service login (which was NOT the DBA's login) no longer had access to the database.  On checking, the service login had indeed lost it's role memberships.

We only had 3 DBAs at the time, and nobody else had access to make a role membership change, so I'm pretty sure that someone did not specifically remove the service login from the roles.  However, I have not seen any warnings on articles about changing owner about something like this occurring, so I've not been able to explain it, and we couldn't reproduce the issue.

So, for example, the database owner was changed from DOMAIN\jdoe, and Windows login "DOMAIN\appuser" mysteriously lost it's built-in role membership.

Is there a situation where changing the owner of the database would cause permission or role changes?

Note that this question pertains to changing the actual database owner, NOT removing a login from the db_owner role.

Comment: Hi Tony. There are a few questions that need to be addressed before this can be answered: **1)** Do you mean an actual role, or just a perceived set of permissions? **2)** If you mean an actual role, is this a server-level role or database-level role? **3)** If you mean an actual role, is it a built-in / fixed role, or user created role? **4)** was access to the DB the only change, or were other operations now denied? **5)** What _exactly_ did you do to fix the situation? Please add the answers to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky 1) A login lost its database role, so that was what prompted the question, but I thought it would make sense to go ahead and add permissions to this question. 2) A database-level role.  3) Built-in.  4) That was the only change noted.  5) The service login was added to the role.

Comment: Tony: **6)** Did the login ever actually lose "access" to the database, or just the role membership (which grants permissions, not access to the DB)? **7)** What built-in role? **8)** Are you 100% certain that, prior to you adding the user to the DB-level role in order to fix the issue, that it was actually a member of that role? **9)** When the DB owner was changed and the app login started having problems, was the app login able to do anything at all, absolutely nothing, or only some stuff?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky 6) Not sure--I wasn't the one that made the change and fixed it. 7) db_owner 8) Yes 9) It just lost the db_owner role on the database, which was the only role it had, so it could then only log in to the server. Also modified question to reflect that the service account is a Windows login.

Comment: Tony, regarding "_It just lost the db_owner role on the database, which was the only role it had, so it could then only log in to the server._": that is not how DB access works. A principal can only be added to a DB role if it already exists in that DB. And, role membership does not control access to the DB; that is controlled by whether or not the account is listed in `sys.database_principals`. So, we are missing something here. Possibly something small, but definitely something. Any other details you can think of?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Yeah--we didn't take time to investigate as it was an important line-of-business application, so we just fixed it ASAP.  The crux of the question is, is there any situation where changing the database owner is expected to affect permissions or role memberships of logins.  If not, then I'm going to assume a mistake was made but not admitted.

Answer (score 4):

If the user is the owner of the database, that user implicitly gets `db_owner` permission, without having to be explicitly assigned that role.

The owner of the database (a single user) is a different assignment than membership in the `db_owner` role, but have the same effect. I like to remember it as the owner of the database is an INSTANCE LEVEL setting (ie, it's in `sys.databases`, but `db_owner` role membership is a DATABASE LEVEL permission.

A user can be ONLY the (server level) database owner, and not have any permissions within that database. When that happens, changing the database owner to sa would effectively lock that user out of the database they previously owned. This would not revoke permissions from the user, but it would change the *effective permissions*.

To avoid this problem, you would need to add the user to the `db_owner` role for that database first, then change the owner.

In the context of your question, if the service account was the prior database owner, then this would explain a change in effective permissions, even though there were no changes to the explicit database-level permission/role assignments.

Comment: Thanks--the service login that lost its role membership was not the ower.  A DBA's login was the owner...

Comment: I think you cannot add the user who is the owner in the db_owner role as you cannot create a user for this login in the DB (the login is already map to the dbo user).
You will need to change the owner of the database first and then create a user for the login that was owning the DB and add it to the db_owner role.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question--the question is whether changing the owner can revoke any permissions or role memberships.  This isn't specific to, nor has it anything to do with, the db_owner role.

Comment: @TonyHinkle You should add to the question that the prior owner was not the service account. As it is written, that detail is a reasonable assumption, particularly for any future readers that might stumble across this question. That detail might change my answer... but please add that to the question.

Comment: This is sentence is not correct "To avoid this problem, you would need to add the user to the db_owner role for that database first, then change the owner.".  It is not possible to grant the db_owner role to someone who owns the database.  You need to reverse the order you have listed.